# Swashbuckle won't generate schema for Enum

Tags: c#, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

I have the following structure
//controller
`GetProducts(string id, [FromQuery] Product)`

//Product.cs class contains an enum member

```
Product 
{
EnumA ExampleA
}
```

```
`//startup.cs
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
    c.UseAllOfToExtendReferenceSchemas();
    }`
```

When trying to inspect the API for getting products using swagger ui, I get a resolver issue for the EnumA, because the in the generated json file there's not definition in components/schemas for the EnumA even though it is referenced in the paths section of the json. Something like this

```
`//paths section of the json
{
    "name": "ExampleA",
    "in": "query",
    "schema": {
    "allOf": [
    {
     "$ref": "#/components/schemas/EnumA"
     }
    ]}
}`
```

I tried a few things,

1. removing `c.UseAllOfToExtendReferenceSchemas();` will actually fix
   this behaviour but, removing this options is not something that
   suits my needs
2. changingthe annotation of the parameter from [FromQuery] to ->
   [FromBody] will also fix this behaviour and have the
   component/schema for this Enum be generated, but also this options
   is something that doesn't suit my need
3. creating a DocumentFilter and trying to manually add this enum for
   the schema definitions using something like
   `swaggerDoc.Components.Schemas.Add("EnumA")` .... will throw and
   error because swashbuckle has this Enum referenced at runtime but
   somehow it's not outputed in the final json file

Tips? (Swashbuckle 5.6.3)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Newtonsoft, you also need this package:

```
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft
```

And in startup:

```
services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport(); // needs to be placed after AddSwaggerGen()
```

You may follow instructions below: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#systemtextjson-stj-vs-newtonsoft